# Not able to enter MySQL terminal using AWS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am running an AWS Ubuntu Instance.

I have installed Apache2, MySQL, PHP and phpmyadmin.

Now I am connected to the AWS instance through SSH, but I want to execute some MySQL commands but I am not able to enter the mysql mode.

After executing the command `sudo mysql`, I am getting an error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Executing the command mysql, I am getting the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ubuntu'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I was able to enter the mysql mode, may be I have changed something during the installation of phpmyadmin, but I am not sure.

I need to enter the mysql mode again.

Apache, MySQL databases and phpmyadmin are working fine.

What should I do to be able to enter the mysql mode to execute some MySQL commands?

EDIT

I am able to execute MySQL command directly using the SQL tab in phpmyadmin, as I have done so far, but I would appreciate a solution to my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ mysql -u <username> -p<password> -h localhost
```

Where both:
*<username>* and *<password>* are the credentials you use to connect to the database via phpMyAdmin.

**Note**: that there is no space between -p and the actual password.